# UserControl DataBinding with data conversion

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I am relatively new to WPF and would like to create a UserControl that contains three RadioBoxes in a StackPanel. Each of the radio buttons has an IsChecked property. I want to ease access to that selection by publishing an integer property that indicates the current selection, call it SelectedIndex.

So when the first radio is checked, the SelectedIndex value of my user control shall be 0; when the second radio is checked, SelectedIndex shall be 1, and so on. This should probably work in either direction: when the user clicks on the radio box, the SelectedIndex value shall change accordingly. And when the SelectedIndex value is changed by code or maybe even some data binding, the UI controls shall update accordingly.

How can I do that with XAML code? I have the following code now:

```
public partial class CommandControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedIndex", typeof(int), typeof(CommandControl));

    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return (int) GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public CommandControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And the XAML part:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.CommandControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="65" d:DesignWidth="219"
             x:Name="me">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="Disable" Name="disableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True" />
        <RadioButton Content="Enable" Name="enableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        <RadioButton Content="Configure" Name="configureRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I know how to pass values (like one of the RadioButton's Text for example) from a property of my UserControl. But this time, I need to map an "external" int value to three "internal" bool values, each true when the number has a specific value. I guess that should be done directly in XAML, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish that.

Or would it be a better idea to write C# code for that conversion? I could possibly do that now, but I'm still unsure about the special DependencyProperty code which, I imagine, may change its value without passing my setter.

Comment: Did you mean to register that SelectedIndex property as being defined by TextUnitControl? Looks like maybe that got copied and pasted from somewhere else?

Comment: Oh yes, that's copied from another UserControl that already uses custom properties. The code above has not really been tried out because I'm very sure something is missing... (Hence this question.) I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common solution is not to attempt to use a numerical representation of which `RadioButton` is selected because you're going against the flow if you try.

However, to try and answer the question nonetheless...

I don't think I'd try to solve this in XAML, because this isn't playing to XAML's strengths. Something people relatively new to WPF often do is to try and do everything possible in XAML whether it makes sense or not because they've got the idea from somewhere that it's what you're supposed to do.

I'm not saying it's impossible. Lest you think I'm trying to talk you out of it because I don't know how to do it in XAML, I'll show exactly how I think you shouldn't do it. This works, for small values of "works":

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyNamespace.CommandControl"
    xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  
    mc:Ignorable="d"  
    d:DesignHeight="65" d:DesignWidth="219" 
x:Name="me">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RadioButton Content="Disable" Name="disableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="True" />
        <RadioButton Content="Enable" Name="enableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        <RadioButton Content="Configure" Name="configureRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>

    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="loc:MyNamespace">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=disableRadio, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=enableRadio, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=configureRadio, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="2" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```

but this is pretty icky. First of all, Visual Studio will pretend there's an error - for as long as you have this Xaml file open it will report the error "'CommandControl' TargetType does not match type of element 'UserControl'." Secondly, this only works if you put the `Style` after the main body of the user control. Frankly these sorts of issues are code smells - a clue that you may be doing things wrong. And in this case, you would be.

By the way, Visaul Studio's not telling the truth with the error message - that's not a compile-time error, and the program will build and run, and using the following main window content:

```
<Grid>
    <my:CommandControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="224,114,0,0" x:Name="commandControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,162,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding ElementName=commandControl1, Path=SelectedIndex}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="237" />
</Grid>
```

I've verified that this does correctly update the property.

But this is all wrong.

For one thing, what you're trying to create here is programatic functionality - you're determining how the control's API behaves. This is well outside XAML's strengths. Heck, even embedding interactive behaviour in XAML is questionable. My view is that XAML is mainly for the layout and appearance of your app.

So the codebehind is really the place for what you're doing. Just use good old-fashioned event handling. Be sure to use `SetCurrentValue` to update your depenedency property's value. Don't just use the setter, because that will mess up any data bindings or other DP-specific uses of your property, and will essentially defeat the point of making it a DP in the first place.

Also, I wouldn't call it `SelectedIndex` because that's a property name that usually means something specific in WPF - it's mainly used by ItemsControl-derived controls that support selection. That's not what you're doing here, so I'd be inclined to pick a name that doesn't already commonly have a meaning. Except as I already said, I don't think I'd be using a numeric index in any case.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should do it in plain C#. XAML everywhere is quite overwhelming with all its numerous new syntaxes: X.Y elements, {Binding x=y} values etc.

But I'm curious, how would you design a control API in this case, if not using a single integer value?

Comment: I've implemented it like this now: The SelectedIndex property setter does not only call SetValue but also update the RadioButtons' IsChecked property accordingly. This works. And I have added Checked event handlers for each RadioButton to call SetCurrentValue or SetValue with the new value. When debugging, I can see that the value of my SelectedIndex wrapper property does change after that call, but the TextBox with my 2way data binding never updates from the buttons (though it updates the buttons when I enter another number). What's wrong here? MSDN articles about it don't seem to cover that.

Comment: You say you're using SetValue? I recommended SetCurrentValue, because SetValue will have precisely the same effect as using the property setter. (After all, your property setter will just be calling SetValue.) If the property is databound, SetValue replaces the binding with the new value. (I.e., it removes the binding.) SetCurrentValue says 'make this the new effective value, but don't blow away any bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Boolean strait up rather than integer = 0 or integer = 1.  Expose a Public Boolean property e.g. rbDisbleIsChecked and bind IsChecked to that property.   If you really want to use Integer for the public property then you will need to use a converter as IsChecked is Boolean.

If you want an Integer to represent the current selected then you could set that value in the set of the boolean public property.

Or you could not bind and just wire all up to the same or separate checked events.  Set the SelectedIndex in the event.  If you wire them all up to the same event then you would need to name them and so the event call determine which was checked.

Comment: My question was about three radio buttons, so I really need a greater type than boolean to represent the current selection.

Comment: @LonelyPixel  Read the answer.  The boolean represents boolean - what the IsChecked requires.  Set an integer in either the set or the event.  An integer is maybe a little big - do you expect 2 billion radio buttons.  A byte at 256 might be a little more realistic.  In the set of the integer call the IsChecked.  IsChecked  is boolean you are going to need to convert to it some where.

Answer (score 0):

Use a value converter like this:

```
public class RadioValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((int)value == Value)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((bool)value == true)
        {
            return Value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the ConvertBack, clicking a RadioButton will always set a true value, so you should never get to the return null.  I don't know of any ways that this would happen at least.

Then in your XAML, you can create a converter for each RadioButton:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <loc:RadioValueConverter x:Key="FirstValue" Value="1"/>
        <loc:RadioValueConverter x:Key="SecondValue" Value="2"/>
        <loc:RadioValueConverter x:Key="ThirdValue" Value="3"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Content="Disable" Name="disableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource FirstValue}}" />
    <RadioButton Content="Enable" Name="enableRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource SecondValue}}" />
    <RadioButton Content="Configure" Name="configureRadio" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource ThirdValue}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This should provide 2-way binding too, so if you change the SelectedIndex elsewhere, the RadioButtons will follow.

Also, I forgot to mention before but this code assumes you've set the DataContext of your CommandControl to itself, ie in the constructor:

```
    public CommandControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Why does every RadioButton that gets deselected have a red border around it?